# How to maintain a minimal/isolated classpath during Maven Surefire tests, when additional test dependencies are in use?

Tags: maven-3, classpath, maven-surefire-plugin

Let's say I am developing a MQ client wrapper library W, based on an existing MQ library suite M. M has `m-client` and `m-server` artifacts, and my W uses `m-client` imported via Maven as a compile-scope dependency.

Now when I write e2e tests for W using Maven Surefire, I can easily add `m-server` as a test-scope dependency; spawn a temporary M server alongside my test; configure and run my W agaist it; and tear down M server when done.

However at runtime, modules of the M suite are known to "interact" in "unpredictable" ways; varying its internal behaviors, depending on the M classes/resources currently available in the classpath.

For example, `m-server` has a hard dependency on another module `m-extras`, and `m-client` also has an *optional* dependency on `m-extras`; so `m-client` may behave differently when `m-extras` is present in the runtime/classpath.

W's intended/production usage environment will not have `m-server` or `m-extras`; just `m-client` pulled in by W. I would like to keep my e2e test runtime as close to the production environment as possible, i.e. free of the side effects caused by `m-extras`. However, because I use `m-server` which mandatorily pulls in `m-extras`, I currently have no way of isolating the (W, `m-client`) "runtime context" within my test (because the test has a flat classpath).

I currently see two workarounds:

- Remove `m-server` from dependencies (so it and `m-extras` won't be present in W's test-runtime classpath, at all); and launch a separate *process* running M (`m-server`) for the duration of the test. This comes with the complexities of having to separately resolve a dependency graph for M, compose its classpath, and the whole process management overhead (plus the risk of leaving behind stray processes in case the test is force-stopped or crashes).
- Within the test, spawn M using a separate classloader that has `m-server` (and its tree) in its classpath (or, do the same for W); still, this requires resolving M's/W's dependency graph for composing the loader's classpath. I looked at the environment and system properties available within a Surefire-driven test to see if Maven/Surefire includes the test and compile-scoped libraries in a "separable" way (so that I can launch either W (client) or M (server) with its own constrained classloader), but could not find anything helpful; the test's classpath is also "flatly resolved" with compile and test dependencies mixed up, so splitting the main classpath into a "compile context" and "test context" also does not seem to be possible.

What would be the proper way to compose and run my test, so that the server dependencies (esp. `m-extras`) will be transparent to the client - while keeping things simple, stable and maintainable?

Comment: First make a separate module `e2e` which contains the dependencies you need and furthermore use maven-failsafe-plugin instead of maven-surefire-plugin...

Comment: I'm rereading this and seeing that you have written the compile/test context is not separated ? The classpath contains first the compile parts (src/main) and last the test parts (src/test/)... The other question is: Which Maven version? JDK Version and plugin versions do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, but how do I ensure that `e2e` and its transitive deps (when used as a test dep) will not 'affect' the `m-client` as stated in the question?

Comment: Also, `src/main/` and `src/test/` are just the project's internal classes; how do I separate out the external dependencies (JARs) as compile and test?

Comment: I'm currently on Maven 3.6 and JDK 11, but it would be nice to have a solution that works for JDK 8+ and Maven 3+ in general

Comment: If you make a separate module `e2e` which has it's own deps and how should it influence `m-client`... it would be helpful to have a full example project to show what you mean...better having a concrete project to talk about..

Comment: @khmarbaise because during the test phase, the classpath will contain both `m-client` and `e2e` (i.e. `m-client` + `m-server` **and** `m-extras` pulled by `e2e`); I didn't think of providing a sample project because this is a generic problem and it is actually not possible to "demonstrate" the *runtime* composed classpath - even if sample project *sources* are provided